# Class vs Type and Object vs Variable

Tags: c++, c

What are the differences and similarities between a class in C++ and a type in C?

```
Class Dog{
...;
}pit bull;
```

Vs.

```
Typedef Struct dog Dog;
Struct dog{
...;
}pit bull;
```

The difference between the Class `Dog` and the Type `Dog` eludes me. Can someone please clarify the real differences between the two?

Thanks in advance ;

Comment: Do you want to know what `typedef` does, or what the differences between `class` and `struct` are?

Comment: Structures in C do not offer encapsulation in the form of private members, nor do they allow you to define methods. This is, however, a very weird question. Why do you care about the difference between two things in two different languages?

Comment: @CodyGray: Excuse me, but a struct can most definitely have methods and private members.

Comment: @beta Not in C it can't.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm sorry, I read your comment too fast; I eat my words.

Comment: I asked the question out of curiosity and the fact that C++ (C with Classes) basically derived from C Language.

Comment: @Unee0x: C++ may have originally evolved from C, but the direction it has taken is totally different. The two should now be regarded as distinct languages.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong:

Comment: No, C and C++ have evolved in parallel from a common ancestor, some sort of ancient C. They are just cousins.

Comment: @CodyGray - take a look at [**Object Oriented Programming in C**](https://ritdml.rit.edu/handle/1850/8544), specifically the .pdf. It is an interesting read.

Comment: I'm sure it is, @David, but I don't have time to read another book at the moment. I can kind of imagine what it says; I've read various (shorter!) articles on simulating OOP in C. And I can never help but wonder what the point is. Either way, in this case, the point is that C structures do not offer any type of encapsulation, and I can only find 'encapsulation' mentioned in that book once and it is unrelated. A C compiler is simply not going to enforce any type of public/private dichotomy.

Comment: The only reason I say it is an interesting read and suggest it, is because it provides an absolute way of associating methods with structs by initializing a base object type at compile-time, the object itself at run-time and forces conversion between inherited objects to give you an actual class implementation with structs. It has it's limitations, (you don't get actual public/private data) but among all the **so-called object oriented Blah** books, this actually provides a workable implementation with data access limitations that renders data private for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the only difference between a class and a struct is that members and base classes are private by default in classes, whereas they are public by default in structs.

So structs can have constructors, and the syntax is the same as for classes.

but in c,
structure can not have methods, constructor and other benefits of classes.

typedef is just an alias or you can say pet name to your class or structure name.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong: if I declare a c struct called Dog in a header file and define it in a c source file and then call Dog's functions in main ,have I not encapsulated c struct called Dog?

Comment: In C, a structure cannot have functions. All they can have is member variables (they are public, of course; C has no concept of access modifiers). So you cannot define or call functions for Dog.

Comment: True, a c struct can not have functions as members; however, a c struct can have function pointers to functions secretly implemented elsewhere, which to me adds a deeper level of security..